# Checking specific radiobutton when navigate to page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

In a windows 8.1 project i have a ListView that displays several items that look something like this:

[image]

I basically display agenda points, that can have 2 sub levels

if subpoint at first level has no subpoints itself it is a radiobutton, otherwise the subpoints it contains are radiobuttons.

the radiobutton points have this template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WithSubTemplate2">

        <Grid Width="280" Height="50" Margin="85,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RadioButton GroupName="meetingFiles" Tag="{Binding}"  Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Content="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"></RadioButton>
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="20" Fill="#b3d0dd" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,10,0"></Ellipse>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttachmentNumber}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  FontFamily="Segoe UI Regular" FontSize="16" Foreground="{StaticResource BrandBrush}" Margin="0, 14,15,0"></TextBlock>
            <Grid x:Name="whiteLine" Grid.Row="1" Width="270" Height="1" Background="#80b0c6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

When i check one of the radio buttons, i have a control that displays a pdf, and then when i want to edit that pdf it navigates to another page.

What i want is, when i go back to the previous page to have the RadioButton i checked earlier to be checked when the page opens.

Any way i can achieve this?

Comment: Can't you simple store the index/name of the radiobutton and retrieve it during the "back" event?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

That'll save current page status :).

Comment: yes, i tried with that, but i had a issue. The radiobutton was indeed checked but the "effect" of having it checked ( in this case a pdf should be displayed) dind't happend.